# managed objects vs. business objects

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to figure out how to use Core Data in my App. I already have in mind what the object graph would be like at runtime:

- An `Account` object owns a `TransactionList` object.
- A `TransactionList` object contains all the transactions of the account. Rather than being a flat list, it organizes transactions per day. So it contains a list of `DailyTransactions` objects sorted by date.
- A `DailyTransactions` contains a list of `Transaction` objects which occur in a single day.

At first I thought Core Data was an ORM so I thought I might just need two tables: `Account` table and `Transaction` table which contained all transactions and set up the above object graph (i.e., organizing transactions per date and generating `DailyTransactions` objects, etc.) using application code at run time.

When I started to learn Core Data, however, I realized Core Data was more of an object graph manager than an ORM. So I'm thinking about using Core Data to implement above runtime object relationship **directly** (it's not clear to me what's the benefit but I believe Core Data must have some features that will be helpful).

So I'm thinking about a data model in Core Data like the following:

```
Acount <--> TransactionList -->> DailyTransactions -->> Transaction
```

Since I'm still learning Core Data, I'm not able to verify the design yet. I suppose this is the right way to use Core Data. But doesn't this put too many implementation details, instead of raw data, in persistent store? The issue with saving implementation details, I think, is that they are far more complex than raw data and they may contain duplicate data. To put it in another way, what exactly does the "data" in data model means, raw data or any useful runtime objects?

An alternative approach is to use Core Data as ORM by defining a data model like:

```
Account <-->> Transactions
```

and setting up the runtime object graph using application code. This leads to more complex application code but simpler database design (I understand user doesn't need to deal with database directly when using Core Data, but still it's good to have a simpler system). That said, I doubt this is not the right way to use Cord Data.

A more general question. I did little database programming before, but I had the impression that there was usually a business object layer above plain old data object layer in server side programming framework like J2EE. In those architectures, objects that encapsulate application business are not same as the objects loaded from database. It seems that's not the case with Core Data?

Thanks for any explanations or suggestions in advance.

(Note: the example above is an simplification. A transaction like transfer involves two accounts. I ignore that detail for simplification.)

Answer (score 0):

Now that I read more about the Core Data, I'll try to answer my own question since no one did it. I hope this may help other people who have the same confusion as I did. Note the answer is based on my current (limited) understanding.

**1. Core Data is an object graph manager for data to be persistently stored**

There are a lot articles on the net emphasizing that Core Data manages object graph and it's not an ORM or database. While they might be technically correct, they unfortunately cause confusion to beginner like me. In my opinion, it's equally important to point out that objects managed by Core Data are not arbitrary runtime objects but those that are suitable for being saved in database. By suitable it means all these objects conform to principles of database schema design.

So, **what' a proper data model is very much a database design question** (it's important to point out this because most articles try to ask their readers to forget about database).

For example, in the account and transactions example I gave above, while I'd like to organize transactions per day (e,g., putting them in a two-level list, first by date, then by transaction timestamp) at runtime. But the best practice in database design is to save all transactions in a single table and generating the two-level list at runtime using application code (I believe so).

So the data model in Core Data should be like:

```
Account <->> Transaction
```

The question left is where I can add the code to generate the runtime structure (e.g., two-level list) I'd like to have. I think it's to extend Account class.

**2. Constraints of Core Data**

The fact that Core Data is designed to work with database (see 1) explains why it has some constraints on the data model design (i.e., attribute can't be of an arbitrary type, etc.).

While I don't see anyone mentioned this on the net, **personally I think relationship in Core Data is quite limited**. It can't be of a custom type (e.g, class) but has to be a variable (to-one) or an array (to-many) at run time. That makes it far less expressive. Note: I guess it's so due to some technical reason. I just hope it could be a class and hence more flexible.

For example, in my App I actually have complex logic between Account and its Transaction and want to encapsulate it into a single class. So I'm thinking to introduce an entity to represent the relationship explicitly:

```
Account <->> AccountTranstionMap <-> Transaction
```

I know it's odd to do this in Core Data. I'll see how it works and update the answer when I finish my app. If someone knows a better way to not do this, please let me know!

**3. Benefits of Core Data**

If one is writing a simple App, (for example, an App that data modal change are driven by user and hence occurs in sequence and don't have asynchronous data change from iCloud), I think it's OK to ignore all the discussions about object graph vs ORM, etc. and just use the basic features of Core Data.

From the documents I have read so far (there are still a lot I haven't finished), the benefits of Core Data includes automatic mutual reference establishment and clean up, live and automatically updated relationship property value, undo, etc. But **if your App is not complex, it might be easier to implement these features using application code**.

That said, it's interesting to learn a new technology which has limitation but at the same time can be very powerful in more complex situations. BTW, just curious, is there similar framework like Core Data on other platforms (either open source or commercial)? I don't think I read about similar things before.

I'll leave the question open for other answers and comments :) I'll update my answer when I have more practical experience with Core Data.